# Android webview request stuck in pending forever

Tags: android, webview

I am showing a programmatically created webview in a bottomsheet fragment. The webview is persisted on a singleton that outlives the fragment
The webview is created like so:

```
webView = WebView(context).let { webView ->
            webView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
            webView.clearCache(true)
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
            webView.measure(100, 100)
            webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
            webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
            webView.addJavascriptInterface(AndroidJavascriptInterface(environment), webViewHook)
            webView.webViewClient = webViewClient
            webView.webChromeClient = webViewChromeClient
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/snippet.html")
            webView
        }
```

and then present the webview in a bottomsheet fragment like so:

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        if (webController == null) {
            // activity restarted without original context
            dismiss()
        } else {
            webController?.webView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            webController?.let {
                fragment_web_view?.addView(webController?.webView)
            }
        }
    }
```

I observe these undesirable behaviors:
The webview's network requests all get stuck at pending when being backgrounded for around 2 min

1. If I persist the webview using a singleton, the webview stops making network request after the webview is presented and then dismissed
2. If I never present the fragment, the webview works fine no matter how long I wait

[Requests start normal but stays pending after a while](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP0fi.png)

But in these two scenarios the webview works fine.

1. If I keep the webview on screen all requests work fine.
2. If I keep presenting and dismissing the webview, all requests works fine.

Is there something that I don’t understand about the android webview that may have caused this issue? In order to refresh the webview, I need to reinitialize it to make the requests work again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an issue with lates version of WebView. Can you open play market on the device find Android System WebView and try to downgrade it. Form me everything works fine on version 74 and stuck in pending on version 99. Let me know if it works same for you or you already found a reason?
[image: version of webview where it works]